# Variations of fonts in CSS not being displayed

Tags: css, fonts

I have a simple font-family statement that goes like this:

```
font-family: "Tw Cen MT Condensed", sans-serif;
```

For some reason, my browser does not recognize this font and displays the default sans-serif font. However, it recognizes Tw Cen MT just fine.

Similarly, it fails to recognize Arial Bold, but finds Arial perfectly. Seemingly, the base font is always recognized, but any variations, e.g., Bold, Condensed, Demi, etc., are not.

I'm on Windows 8 and these fonts are installed on my system. I've tried this in IE, FF, and Chrome. The files are local, but uploading to a server doesn't change anything. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have all font packages uploaded? By that I mean the 4 standard extensions. eot, svg, woff, ttf

Comment: Yes, I do. Should probably mention that Tw Cen MT and its Condensed counterpart come with Win8 if it wasn't clear already.

Comment: Have you tried running one through fontsquirrel's font kit generator? Maybe something's corrupt. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 1):

In font-family use only the font name I.e. "Tw Cen MT" then assign the value of font-stretch:condensed; 
Instead of using direct font name use the base font then change the following properties:

```
font-stretch
font-variant
font-style
font-weight
line-height
font-size
font-family
```

Comment: This works fine in FF but Chrome does not support font-stretch.